# Как правильно: "прочесть" или "прочитать" ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли по-русски говорить: "прочитал", "прочитала"? Или надо "прочёл", "прочла"?

Comment: Я всегда придерживался правильному РУССКОМУ языку. Меня этому учили. Но, когда говорят "Я ПРОЧЕЛ, а не ПРОЧИТАЛ, меня это коробит!". Вы можете сказать, что ЧИТАТЕЛЬ и ЧТЕЦ однозначные слова. Соглашусь. Но ЧИТАТЕЛЬ читает для себя, а ЧТЕЦ, для публики. Отбросим приставку ПРО. ПРОЧИТАТЬ - ЧИТАТЬ, ПРОЧЕСТЬ - ЧЕСТЬ. ЧИТАТЬ и ЧЕСТЬ совершенно разные по значению слова! Берегите РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК!

Comment: *Я всегда придерживался правильному РУССКОМУ языку* - все, спасибо. Вы приняты на отделение пародистов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Есть ответ на сайте [gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_48)

**Вопрос**

Как правильно: ***прочитать*** и ***прочесть***?
Глаголы прочитать и прочесть совершенного вида. Эти глаголы совпадают во всех значениях, кроме значения глагола прочитать - «провести какое-либо время за чтением» (ср.: нормальное *прочитать всю ночь*, но неверное *прочесть всю ночь*).
Формообразование у глаголов прочесть и прочитать различается.

***Прочесть***: *прочту, прочтёшь, прочтёт, прочтём, прочтёте, прочтут, прочёл, прочла, прочло, прочли, прочтённый, прочтя.*

***Прочитать***: *прочитаю, прочитаешь, прочитает, прочитаем, прочитаете, прочитают, прочитанный, прочитав.*

Глагол ***прочесть*** относится к непродуктивным классам (группам) глаголов, глагол ***прочитать*** - к 1 продуктивному классу глаголов, чем и объясняется его б*о*льшая употребительность.

**Правильно**

*прочесть* и *прочитать книгу*, но только *прочитать всю ночь*.

Comment: Т.е. вполне нормально написать по-русски так: 
Я прочитал книгу Достоевского "Идиот"

Это не выглядит менее литературно и правильно, чем:
Я прочёл книгу...

Мне вот эти нюансы восприятия интересны. Как воспринимается в речи "я прочитал" и "я прочёл". Равнозначно?

Comment: В принципе да. ***"Я прочёл"*** - короче аж на целый слог, что в устной речи может быть приятно. С другой стороны, на мой слух, слово ***"прочитал"*** более литературно, что ли.

Если обратить внимание на смысловую нагрузку [***"прочитать"***][1] и [***"прочесть"***][2], то можно обратить, что у ***"прочитать"*** есть один дополнительный смысл: ***"провести некоторое время, читая."***

[1]:http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C
[2]:http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Как-таки правильно,  "я прочитал эту книгу" или "я прочёл эту книгу", и почему?

Answer (score 5):

Думаю, что глаголы «прочесть» и «прочитать» в некоторых случаях отличаются оттенками значений. Например: прочитать книгу, но прочесть лекцию или прочесть наставление, также: хороший чтец, но хороший читатель.
Можно условно сказать, что форма «прочесть»  передает внутренний, активный, «авторский» характер действия, в то время как форма «прочитать» в большей степени пассивная и «завязанная»  на внешний объект. Такую же картину можно наблюдать во многих парных вариантах с суффиксом А и без него, например: рыбы мечут икру – спортсмен метает копье, брызжет фонтан – не брызгай водой, каплет (капает) дождь – не капай на пол.

Answer (score 3):

Прочитал (книгу, письмо) - безусловно правильно. 
Прочел - вариант более редкий, чаще именно он воспринимается как просторечный или устаревающий, хотя словари этого не подтвреждают: варианты даются как равноправные.

О втором значении "прочитать", которого нет у "прочесть", вам уже сказали.

Answer (score 2):

Важно понимать то, что слова эти могут употребляться по смыслу.

Например: "Я **прочитал** книгу Л.Н. Толстого "Война и мир"" (то есть я это сделал), **НО** "Я **прочёл** в романе Л.Н. Толстого "Война и мир", как Наташа Ростова танцевала на балу". То есть мы видим, что слово **"прочитать"** в данном смысле означает как обозначение факта совершения определённого действия, а слово **"прочесть"** подразумевает под собой непосредственно содержание действия, углубление в детали происходящего.

Также можно сказать, что я **прочитал** научно-познавательную **газету**, но я **прочёл в ней об одном открытии**, которые учёные сделали в микробиологии/астрономии/географии и так далее.

Ещё один пример: "Прочитай учебник по истории", "Прочти, что написано в параграфе 21". Вот примерно таким образом и можно эти слова употреблять.

Comment: Интересное разделение, но оно не подтверждается ни практикой, ни словарями. По современным представлениям "прочел" и "прочитал" трактуются и используются как очень близкие синонимы, разделение идут по линии нормативности, "прочел" считается несколько сниженным, хотя раньше, еще лет сто назад и такого не было.

Comment: не понял, столько слов, но если взять тот же приведенный и сразу же заброшенный незаконченый пример, как таки "правильно" говорить: я прочитал книгу Л.Н. Толстого "Война и мир" или я прочёл книгу Л.Н. Толстого "Война и мир"? и где такие правила определены, кстати, но это уже другая тема

Answer (score 0):

Прочитать - говорит о скольжении взгляда по тексту, распознавая слова и понимая суть написанного. Прочесть - говорит об озвучивании текста. Это разные понятия. 
Чтец прочтёт, а читатель прочитает. Но... 
"Чтец прочёл" - прочёл по памяти стихотворение. 
"Чтец прочитал" - имеется в виду, например, что чтец (человек, который прочёл стих по памяти), после прочтения стиха, прочитал что-то безмолвно. 
"Читатель прочитал" - например: прочитал о каком-то событии из газеты. 
"Читатель прочёл" - имеется в виду, например, что читатель безмолвно прочитал текст из книги, а потом прочёл его по памяти.