# "Прочти" и "прочитай": равнозначные ли?

Tags: лексика

Собственно, вопрос содержится в заголовке: являются ли равнозначными слова "прочти" и "прочитай"? Аналогичная ситуация со словами "сочти" и "сосчитай", но "сочти" мне видится устаревшим.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: О-о-о, в одном из моих любимых рассказов - "Перед обедом мать сочла сливы..." Толстой "Косточка"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылку на прочесть/прочитать Вам уже давали.

В отношении "счесть" и "сосчитать".
У "счесть" - два (или даже три - по Кузнецову) значения, сейчас обычно используется в том, которое ранее считалось переносным - воспринять, расценить. Значение же, синонимичное "посчитай" почти не используется. В этом смысле слова неравнозначны, хотя в остальном значения полностью совпадают.

Answer (score 1):

Да, равнозначны. Более подробный ответ дан в аналогичном вопросе: [ССЫЛКА](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7596/%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)

С глаголами **счесть** (сочту) и **сосчитать** (сосчитай) история такая же.